# In Kendo MVVM, stop binding at child container

Tags: mvvm, kendo-ui

The kendo docs for kendo.bind state that it will automatically traverse all descendents. I'm creating a composite UI for a microservice backend and I have separate VM's for each component, but I also want to bind to the page containing all of the components. When I bind to the page, it automatically tries to bind to all of the components on the page when I only want to bind to one or two elements in the same page container. This article talks about a way to stop Knockout from binding child elements:
http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/05/quick-tip-skip-binding.html

Is there a way to accomplish this with Kendo?

Answer (score -1):

I just looked through the source code and found (in version 2016.1.406) that if you bind to the source attribute then it bails out of the recursive portion of kendo.bind. See here:

[image]

So all I had to do was bind to the source of the container to null:
[image]